# Mothballs coffeepot

Tags: kitchen-safety

Had a coffeepot in storage a few packaged mothballs fell in water reservoir proceeded to rinse with hot water vinegar rinse multiple times is it now safe to use

Comment: when in doubt - throw it out

Comment: Welcome to SA!  You'll be happy to know that your question has already been answered: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/95604/should-i-clean-all-of-my-cooking-utensils-after-being-exposed-to-mothballs-naph